# Notification Listener Behaving Strangely when Backgrounded

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, stdout, stdin

**I've been struggling to get my IRC-Bouncer/Notification Script working.**

This is meant to be a script which will automatically login to a remote machine, attach to a screen session (or start one if none currently exists) running weechat, while simultaneously opening another ssh connection which uses netcat to read notifications from a socket-file to which a [weechat add-on-script](https://github.com/kelsin/weechat-socket-notify) exports my notification messages.  These notifications are then fed into lib-notify (via notify-send) so that I can be alerted of activity in weechat.

**Here's the script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BOUNCER="MYUSER@MYBOUNCER.NET"

function irc_notify() {
  ssh $BOUNCER "nc -k -l -U /tmp/weechat.notify.sock" | \
    while read type message; do
     notify-send -i weechat -u critical "$(echo -n $type | base64 -di -)" "$(echo -n $message | base64 -di -)"
    done
}

# Start listening for notifications
irc_notify &

# Attach to remote IRC Bouncer Screen
ssh $BOUNCER -t 'screen -d -R -S irc weechat'

# Cleanup Socket Listener
echo "cleaning up notification socket listener…"
ssh $BOUNCER 'pkill -f -x "nc -k -l -U /tmp/weechat.notify.sock"'
```

**The setup actually works really well, except for one major glitch.**  Only two notifications were making it through to my notification manager, per invocation of the script.  After that: nothing.

So to eliminate issues with the notification script in weechat, I removed the second ssh invocation (the one which attaches to the screen session and starts weechat) and replaced it with a `read` command to block execution while I tested.  Then, using `irb` on the remote machine, I sent messages to the socket with ruby.
However, **even when I was sending the messages manually, still only two messages would appear before it stopped working**.

`strace` showed me some interesting behavior (when I attached to the forked process) where it seemed that the messages stopped being terminated by new-line characters after the first or second message.  But after a few more, they stopped appearing in `strace` all-together.

**At this point I decided to see if there was something in my script that was causing strange behavior.**  So on the command-line I simply invoked the ssh connection (`ssh $BOUNCER "nc -k -l -U /tmp/weechat.notify.sock"`) directly.  And lo-and-behold, all the messages I was sending manually were appearing (still base64 encoded, of course).

So then I added on the logic to decode every message as it came in, like I had in my script, and it also worked perfectly for every message.  Including when I fed these messages into notify-send.

So at this point **I decided that something strange must be happening when I forked the function**.  But I observed no difference in effectiveness when I back-grounded the commands in the terminal.  So I wondered if perhaps something strange was happening because it was being run from within a script.

## That's when things got weird…

I began by breaking the logic out of the function, and just invoking it directly, with an ampersand at the end of the piped commands.  Like so:

```bash
ssh $BOUNCER "nc -k -l -U /tmp/weechat.notify.sock" | \
  while read type message; do
    notify-send -i weechat -u critical "$(echo -n $type | base64 -di -)" "$(echo -n $message | base64 -di -)"
  done &
```

**As soon as I did that, the messages suddenly started working.  And as soon as I reverted the change, I was back to square one with the same strange two-message-only behavior.**

But this fix, introduced some other strange behavior.  **Once I was inside the screen session, I would have to hit each key multiple times before it was registered by the program.  As if there was a race-condition fighting over STDIN.**

Figuring perhaps the two SSH sessions were fighting over it (though I wasn't sure why) I tried to close and/or occupy STDIN on the first ssh command through various means.  Such as by piping in `: |` before it, or appedning  `<&-` or  `</dev/null` after the SSH portion of the pipe.  And while that did seem to resolve the race-condition, this reintroduced the two-message-only behavior.

Thinking that **it might have something to do with being under multiple-layers of sub-processing**, I then attempted to reproduce this by wrapping the SSH call with `bash -c` like so: `bash -c 'ssh $BOUNCER "nc -k -l -U /tmp/weechat.notify.sock" &'`.  And this too exhibited the two-message-only behavior.

I also went ahead and tested this directly on the remote machine (SSHing to localhost, and wrapping in two `bash -c` invocations) and witnessed the same broken behavior.  **It also does not seem to be related to double forking causing orphaned processes.**  As it does not seem to matter if the process ends up orphaned or not.

**I also verified this is also happening under `zsh`**.

It seems that this is somehow related to the way which STDIN and STDOUT are treated when a process is run under layers of sub-processing.

## Repro. Instructions & `strace` Output:

In order to simplify debugging I removed SSH from the picture and wrote two simplified test scripts which successfully reproduced the behavior entirely locally.

Using the Juergen Nickelsen's `socket` command I created a local UNIX Domain Socket (`socket -l -s ./test.sock`), and once again was able to send test messages to it with `irb` using the following chunk of Ruby code:

```ruby
require 'socket'
require 'base64'

SOCKET = './test.sock'

def send(subtitle, message)
  UNIXSocket.open(SOCKET) do |socket|
    socket.puts "#{Base64.strict_encode64(subtitle)} #{Base64.strict_encode64(message)}"
  end
end

send('test', 'hi')
send('test', 'hi')
send('test', 'hi')
send('test', 'hi')
send('test', 'hi')
send('test', 'hi')
```

**The First Script** only backgrounded the piped expression (which, as previously stated, processed an unlimited number of messages):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
# to aid in cleanup when using Ctrl-C to exit strace
trap "pkill -f -x 'nc -k -l -U $HOME/test.sock'; exit" SIGINT
 
# Start listening for notifications
nc -k -l -U $HOME/test.sock | \
  while read type message; do
    # write messages to a local file instead of sending to notification daemon for simplicity.
    echo "$(echo -n $type | base64 -di -)" "$(echo -n $message | base64 -di -)" >> /tmp/msg
  done &
 
read
```

And produced the following output when run with `strace -f`: http://pastebin.com/SMjti3qW

**The Second Script** backgrounded the wrapping function (which triggers the 2-and-done behavior):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# to aid in cleanup when using Ctrl-C to exit strace
trap "pkill -f -x 'nc -k -l -U $HOME/test.sock'; exit" SIGINT

# Start listening for notifications
function irc_notify() {
  nc -k -l -U $HOME/test.sock | \
    while read type message; do
      # write messages to a local file instead of sending to notification daemon for simplicity.
      echo "$(echo -n $type | base64 -di -)" "$(echo -n $message | base64 -di -)" >> /tmp/msg
    done
}

irc_notify &

read
```

And which, in turn, produced this following output when run with `strace -f`: http://pastebin.com/WsrXX0EJ

**One thing which stands out to me when looking at the `strace` output from the above scripts is the output specific to the `nc` command**.  Which seems to show one of the main differences between the execution of these two scripts.

**The First script's** "working" `nc` `strace` output:

```c
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3,
```

**The Second Script's** "2-and-done" Behavior seen in `nc` `strace` output:

```c
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 4
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 2 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=0, revents=POLLHUP}])
read(4, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
shutdown(4, 1 /* send */)               = 0
close(0)                                = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(4, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(4, 0 /* receive */)            = 0
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 0
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 2 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(0, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 2048)        = 14
write(1, "dGVzdA== aGk=\n", 14)         = 14
read(0, "", 2048)                       = 0
shutdown(0, 1 /* send */)               = 0
close(0)                                = 0
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
.......[truncated].......
```

I'm not where I'd like to be in regards to my `strace` output readability, so I'm not exactly sure what these different outputs imply—aside from the fact that one is obviously working while the other is not.

As I've dug through the larger `strace` output, it also seems that messages after the first two are no longer terminated by a newline?  But again, I'm not sure what that implies, or if I'm reading it correctly.

And I definitely do not understand how the different sub-processing techniques, or even closing STDIN, could be affecting this behavior.

**Any idea what I'm encountering here?**

--

### tl;dr

**I'm trying to figure out why running my notification listener under more than one-layer of sub-processing results in only two messages being processed; and not doing so results in a race-condition on STDIN.**

Comment: Note that `ssh -n` will prevent reading from stdin, though this doesn't seem to be the cause of the main issue. What does `strace` of the `nc` process show when compared to the subprocess? Is `nc` receiving and emitting data? Is it blocking? Does closing stdout for the subprocess have any effect?

Comment: adding `-n` to ssh seems to have the same effect as any other attempt to close STDIN (two and done behavior). As does closing STDIN on the subprocess.

I ran `strace` on `nc` though, and it does show some interesting behavioral differences between scenarios where all messages get through (http://pastebin.com/tCSwtA99), and when only two get through (http://pastebin.com/gZueVpb0).

I'm not the best at reading `strace` output.  I may have to dig through some system call documentation to make sense of this.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `strace -f` ? That will follow forks to include traces from all subprocesses spawned.

Comment: adding `-f` to the `nc` `strace` doesn't have any effect, since `nc` does not fork at all.  I'd give you the full output of running that on the client-side script, but what this provides is so long and contains so much sensitive information (from LDAP, etc.) that I can't properly sanitize to paste here.  But I can tell you that, what I always observe when I try this that two messages are always passed through, but the last one does not appear to be properly terminated (it's missing a new-line character) or something, and that seems to coincide with when `nc` starts spewing `poll()` messages.

Comment: OK.  So I reproduced this behavior after removing SSH from the picture and doing everything locally—which resulted in cleaner `strace` output.  I ran two versions of this test script with `strace -f`; one which backgrounded the piped expression and would process unlimited test messages (http://pastebin.com/GDjxTJuJ), and one which backgrounded a wrapping function and which only processed two messages before breaking (http://pastebin.com/GMtkKefP).  The `strace -f` output of these respective scripts was 1) http://pastebin.com/SMjti3qW, and 2) http://pastebin.com/WsrXX0EJ

Comment: Edited question to include these further test results along with repro. steps.

Comment: Try adding `-d` to the `nc` command, which will prevent `nc` from attempting to read from stdin. In the second case above, where you background the function, stdin is closed before the pipeline is created. The result is that on the first `poll`, `nc` reads EOF from stdin and closes fd 0. The next call to `accept` yields a client on fd 0. After that client disconnects, `nc` gets into an endless loop as it attempts to `poll` repeatedly on the closed fd 0 (which it thinks is stdin, which should never close). In the first command, stdin is left open, so this case doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer derivatives of the OpenBSD `netcat`, including FreeBSD[1] and Debian[2], support a `-d` flag which prevents reading from stdin and fixes the problem you described.

The problem is that netcat is polling stdin as well as its "network" fd, and stdin is reopened from `/dev/null` in the second case above, where the shell function is run in the background before the pipeline is created. That means an immediate EOF on the first read from stdin (fd 0), but netcat will continue to `poll(2)` on the now-closed stdin, creating an endless loop.

Here is the redirection of stdin before the pipeline creation:

```
249 [pid 23186] open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
251 [pid 23186] <... open resumed> )        = 3
253 [pid 23186] dup2(3, 0)                  = 0
254 [pid 23186] close(3)                    = 0
```

Now when netcat (pid 23187) calls its first `poll(2)`, it reads EOF from stdin and closes fd 0:

```
444 [pid 23187] poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 2 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=0, revents=POLLIN}])
448 [pid 23187] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
450 [pid 23187] <... read resumed> "", 2048) = 0
456 [pid 23187] close(0 <unfinished ...>
458 [pid 23187] <... close resumed> )       = 0
```

The next call to `accept(2)` yields a client on fd 0, which is now the lowest-numbered free fd:

```
476 [pid 23187] accept(3,  <unfinished ...>
929 [pid 23187] <... accept resumed> {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 0
```

Note here that netcat is now including fd 0 in the args to `poll(2)` twice: once for `STDIN_FILENO`, which is always included in the absence of the `-d` command-line parameter, and once for the newly-connected client:

```
930 [pid 23187] poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 2 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
```

The client sends EOF and netcat disconnects:

```
936 [pid 23187] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
938 [pid 23187] <... read resumed> "", 2048) = 0
940 [pid 23187] shutdown(0, SHUT_WR <unfinished ...>
942 [pid 23187] <... shutdown resumed> )    = 0
944 [pid 23187] close(0 <unfinished ...>
947 [pid 23187] <... close resumed> )       = 0
```

But now it's in trouble because it will continue to poll on fd 0, which is now closed. The netcat code does not handle the case of `POLLNVAL` being set in the `.revents` member of `struct pollfd`, so it gets into an endless loop, never to call `accept(2)` again:

```
949 [pid 23187] poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, 4294967295 <unfinished ...>
951 [pid 23187] <... poll resumed> )        = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
953 [pid 23187] poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}, {fd=-1}], 2, 4294967295 <unfinished ...>
955 [pid 23187] <... poll resumed> )        = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLNVAL}])
...
```

In the first command, where the pipeline is backgrounded but is not run in a shell function, stdin is left open, so this case doesn't arise.

Code references (see the `readwrite` function):

1. http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/netcat/
2. https://sources.debian.net/src/netcat-openbsd/1.105-7/

Comment: Ah!  So that explains why backgrounding the function *and* various methods of closing STDIN resulted in the *exact* same behavior.  Because they all resulted in a pipeline to nowhere for for `nc`.  I had been so concerned with sub-processing, when instead the problem was in the file-descriptors.  This completely solved my problem and provided a detailed explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: Question: shouldn't SIGTTIN deal with this sort of behavior and prevent the race-condition on STDIN?  Does this mean that `nc` is simply not honoring the Signal?

Comment: If the parent did not close (or redirect) STDIN, and `nc` attempted to read from it, then yes, it would receive SIGTTIN, because STDIN is still attached to your terminal. You can observe this by running `cat &` in your shell, and noting that it is immediately stopped due to SIGTTIN. In the case above, however, the parent redirects STDIN from `/dev/null`, which has the effect of disconnecting STDIN from your tty. Then when `nc` reads fd 0, it is reading from `/dev/null`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand how this works when it only processes two messages.  But I'm referring to when I encountered the race-condition when I only backgrounded the piped expression and then found that Only some of my keystrokes were getting read by weechat over SSH.

Comment: To correct my earlier comment, `nc` would only receive the signal upon `read(2)` if you started its pipeline from an interactive shell (i.e., not from a script), since it would then be in the background. But here, in a shell script which is in the foreground, the subprocesses (`ssh`/`nc` pipeline, `ssh ... screen`) are part of the same process group, so no signal is delivered. When you backgrounded the pipeline, you were indeed seeing a case where two processes were "fighting" over STDIN, because both were part of the same foreground process group that had access to the controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem go away if you run the function like this?

```
irc_notify </dev/null &
```

If so, the problem is probably two processes simultaneously trying to read from stdin. Running all ssh commands with -n, like zackse suggested, might also help, at least to debug which processes are fighting over stdin.

Comment: Same result as if I don't put the `</dev/null`.  I don't get the race-condition on STDIN, but only two messages make it through.